# mysql SQL optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

this query takes an hour

```
select *,
      unix_timestamp(finishtime)-unix_timestamp(submittime) timetaken 
from joblog 
where jobname like '%cas%' 
and submittime>='2013-01-01 00:00:00' 
and submittime<='2013-01-10 00:00:00'
order by id desc limit 300;
```

but the same query with one `submittime` finishes in like .03 seconds

the table has 2.1 Million rows

Any idea whats causing the issue or how to debug it

Comment: Please properly format your code before posting. http://sqlformat.appspot.com/ is a good tool for SQL.

Comment: From [B-Tree Index Characteristics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-btree-hash.html): "*The index also can be used for `LIKE` comparisons if the argument to `LIKE` is a constant string that **does not start with a wildcard character.***" (my emphasis)

Comment: What do you mean *query with one submittime* is fast?  You mean if you run `submittime > x` rather than `submittime between x and y`?

Comment: Do you have an index on submittime?

Comment: no is it a good idea to have an index on timestamp?

Comment: added an index still no use [link](http://pastebin.com/V3MHSf1E)

Comment: If you have an index on submittime try replacing: "and submittime>='2013-01-01 00:00:00' 
and submittime<='2013-01-10 00:00:00'" with: "and submittime BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-10 00:00:00' " to see if the MySQL optimizer will recognize the possibility of an index range scan

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be to use [MySQL EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see what the query is doing. It'll probably give you some insight on how to fix your issue.

My guess is that `jobname LIKE '%cas%'` is the slowest part because you're doing a wildcard text search. Adding an index here won't even help, because you have a leading wildcard. Is there any way to do this query without a leading wildcard like that? Also adding an index on `submittime` might improve the speed of this query.

Comment: yes i tried without '%cas% and it worked fine. but with cas added a 23 second latency

Comment: there is no difference with or without cas in the the output of explan http://pastebin.com/MG1D4uSB

Comment: I'm not sure, but you should post the EXPLAIN output in your question for others to see.

Comment: i did its there in the paste bin link

Comment: mysql> select * from(select *,unix_timestamp(finishtime)-unix_timestamp(submittime) timetaken from joblog where   submittime>='2013-01-01 00:00:00' and submittime<='2013-01-10 00:00:00' ) as a where jobname like '%cas%'
    -> ;  added a subquery but how do i make it faster

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a LIMIT to the query and see if that increases the speed that it returns ...

Excerpt from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

"Sometimes MySQL does not use an index, even if one is available. One circumstance under which this occurs is when the optimizer estimates that using the index would require MySQL to access a very large percentage of the rows in the table. (In this case, a table scan is likely to be much faster because it requires fewer seeks.) However, if such a query uses LIMIT to retrieve only some of the rows, MySQL uses an index anyway, because it can much more quickly find the few rows to return in the result. "

Comment: i am using a limit of 300 here but still its slow

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,unix_timestamp(finishtime)-unix_timestamp(submittime) timetaken  
from joblog  
where   (submittime between '2013-01-10 00:00:00'  and  '2013-01-19 00:00:00')   
and jobname is not null 
and jobname like '%cas%';
```

this helped

(0.93 seconds)